# A tweet example with symbols field in entities object

Tags: twitter, tweepy, tweets, twython

According to Twitter (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/entities-object), "symbols" filed in entities object represents symbols, i.e. $cashtags, included in the text of the Tweet. However, whatever I tried to find a tweet example that has a "symbol" entity I couldn't. Can anyone show me a tweet with symbol field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search on twitter for any stock symbol like `$TWTR` you should find some examples, eg: https://twitter.com/TEV_Capital/status/1173855569037295617

```
"entities": {
    "hashtags": [],
    "symbols": [
      {
        "text": "TWTR",
        "indices": [
          29,
          34
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "AKAM",
        "indices": [
          35,
          40
        ]
      },
...
```